# "Undeclared" value for value declared inside struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stack, undeclared-identifier

I'm trying to implement/understand stacks and I keep getting "value undeclared" for something that is declared inside the struct that is supposed to represent the stack

```
#define EmptyTOS ( -1 )
#define MinStackSize ( 5 )

typedef struct StackRecord *Stack;

struct StackRecord
{
    int Capacity;
    int TopOfStack;
    int *Array;
};

Stack CreateStack( int MaxElements )
{
    Stack S;    
    S = malloc( sizeof( struct StackRecord ) );
    S->Array = malloc( sizeof( int ) * MaxElements );
    S->Capacity = MaxElements;
    MakeEmpty( S );
    return S;
}

void MakeEmpty( Stack S ){
    S->TopOfStack = EmptyTOS;
}

void Push( int X, Stack S ){
    S->Array[++TopOfStack] = X;
}

int main(){

    Stack s1 = CreateStack(10);

    return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile just this I get: In function ‘Push’: error: ‘TopOfStack’ undeclared
I don't understand why

Comment: `S->Array[++TopOfStack]` -> `S->Array[++S->TopOfStack]`

Comment: See the above comment.  `TopOfStack` is a structure member, not a local variable.  In `Push`, you need to access it through a structure pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `TopOfStack` is not declared.

If you want to access the member variable of the object pointed at by `S`, you should write `S->TopOfStack`.

Comment: Thank you so much! teacher forgot to add and/or mention that :/